# Get result from two queries in single Content by search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, query, content-search-web-part

First of all I would like to say that my requirement is a bit different.
   Consider there is a list as below.

[image]

Here I want to retrieve and show the items in content search webpart in the following order.

1) I want the top 1 list item with latest Date after grouping by GroupId, in the ascending order of GroupId to be shown on the top.
2) Then all the remaining items in Descending order by Date to be shown after the above items.

**The result would be like this :**
[image]

Now am using two Content search webparts(Webpart A & Webpart B) to show this.
I have written query for the top result and it is working fine. In the second web part am retrieving all the list items without filtering any items in Descending order of Date and displaying the item only if it is not present(by checking in the html document) in the top webpart.

Now what I want is, i need to use single content search webpart to show these results.

I am not sure how can I achieve this using single CSWP webpart.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.